# table reloadData not called

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a viewcontroller which contains a tableview. I call another view via pushViewController. When I get back to my original viewController I hope to redraw the table, but viewWillAppear is never called.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two classes competing for messages, UITabbarcontroller and UINavigationController. I had a UITabBar from a previous experiment. It was created but not used. The messages where getting to UITabBarController, and UINavigationController was never told.

Hope this solution will help someome someday

Answer (score 1):

I've used this in my own projects with success.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

Double check the spelling of the method.